# Get Model.all with associations and return as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to get all records from my model with associated records as well and then generate json with `.to_json`. I'm using Rails **2.3**.

Here is piece of part of the model:

```
class Currency
    has_many :exchange_from, :class_name => "CurrencyExchange", :foreign_key => "currency_from_id", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :exchange_to, :class_name => "CurrencyExchange", :foreign_key => "currency_to_id", :dependent => :destroy
```

And that is code that I thought will work:

```
Currency.all(:include => [:exchange_from, :exchange_to]).to_json
```

But result is exacly *the same* as I would do simply `Currency.all.to_json`. If it's impossible to achive my goal using ActiveRecord please guide me what kind of SQL should I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
Currency.all(:include => [:exchange_from, :exchange_to]).to_json(:include => [:exchange_from, :exchange_to])
```

[Documentation here.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)